# W2K12 Server Manager and WinRM SSL

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

does anyone know if it is possible to use Server Manager on remote servers using SSL? Due to enterprise policies we currently disable winrm listeners for http and enable https only.
This works fine for get-pssession using the -UseSSL switch. 
Adding servers to server groups works in general with enabled winrm/http listener on the remote server. With https enabled only I get the error:

> Online - Verify WinRM 3.0 service is installed, running and the
>   firewall ports are open

So Server Manager does not seem to try SSL.
This impacts minor tasks like the dhcp-role postconfiguration on local servers as well, but there are workarounds at least.